# MySQL syntax error? JDBC

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, syntax

Im pretty new to SQL and I'm using JDBC. Now I've got something that seems like a Syntax error but i can't seem to find the problem... The error is

> SQL-Exception in DBConnection.executeSelectQuery() SQLException: You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a, (SELECT
>   a.id AS id, a.startpunkte+t1.pkte AS pkte             FROM arzt a, (SELECT a.i'
>   at line 1 SQLState: 42000 VendorError: 1064

while my statement is

```
SELECT a.id, a.ansage_id, a.name, a.vorname,  a.strasse, a.hausnummer, a.stadt, a.aktiv, a.wertung, t.pkte 
FROM arzt a, (SELECT a1.id AS id, a1.startpunkte+t1.pkte AS pkte
          FROM arzt a1, (SELECT a2.id, SUM(t.punkte) AS pkte
            FROM arzt a2, dienst d, tag t
            WHERE d.arzt_id = a2.id
            AND t.id = d.tag_id
        ) AS t1
    WHERE t1.id=a1.id
    ) AS t
WHERE a.id = t.id
ORDER BY a.name
```

I hope somebody could help me. sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You have used `arzt a,` same alise in two place change it as unique like `arzt a` `arzt b`!!

Comment: Mysql or SqlServer? Error seems to by MySql, so I've moved SqlServer tag

Comment: Actually `a` alias used 3 times, and there also double `t` alias

Comment: Ichanged the as to unique ones, but the problem still occurs. Im sorry for the tag problem :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by the `artz.id` for the `SUM()` to work correctly. I've also changed the `WHERE` JOINS to `INNER JOINS`, to improve readability:

```
SELECT a.id, a.ansage_id, a.name
FROM arzt a
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT a.id AS id, a.startpunkte+t1.pkte AS pkte 
        FROM arzt a INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT a.id, SUM(t.punkte) AS pkte 
            FROM arzt a
                INNER JOIN dienst d
                ON d.arzt_id = a.id
                INNER JOIN tag t 
                ON t.id = d.tag_id 
            GROUP BY a.id) AS t1 
        ON t1.id=a.id ) AS t 
    ON a.id = t.id 
ORDER BY a.name;
```

[Dataless fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d6167/4)

As others have mentioned, reusing the same aliases in the subqueries is confusing. I've updated in the Fiddle.

Comment: This actually worked. (t gave me an empty result set) but still thanks i guess there is just data missing

Comment: If you can supply data to the sql fiddle, it would help debug.